# Django ORM giving error when trying to use User with additional info

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using Django 1.4 with Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Edit:  I'm clearing some of the erroneous portions of this question out as it appears the same problem has re-occurred.  It was working wonderfully - I made no changes - and now it's failing.  What's up with that?

This is basically what the views look like:

```
@login_required
def request_new_project(request):
    """
    ..  function:: request_new_project()

        Collect information to call the form used to create a new project

        :param request: Django Request object
    """
    user_dict = { 'rsb_username'  : request.user.username}
    form = CreateProject(initial = user_dict)
    data = { 'user' : request.user }
    data.update(csrf(request))
    data.update({ 'form' : form })

    return render_to_response("create_project.html", data)

@login_required
def add_project(request):
    """
    ..  function:: add_project()

        Add a project for the user

        :param request: Django Request object
    """

    if (request.method == "POST"):
        user = User.objects.get(username = request.POST.get('rsb_username'))
        userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(user = user)

        new_project = Projects(client = userProfile,
                               project_name = request.POST.get('rsb_project_name'),
                               description = request.POST.get('rsb_description'),
                               budget = request.POST.get('rsb_budget'),
                               time_frame = request.POST.get('rsb_time_frame'),
                               time_frame_units = request.POST.get('rsb_time_frame_units'),
                               contact = request.POST.get('rsb_point_of_contact'),
                               contact_email = request.POST.get('rsb_contact_email'),
                               contact_phone = request.POST.get('rsb_contact_phone'),
                               price_quote = 0,
                               eta = 'To Be Determined',
                               current_status = 'Waiting for quote',
                               )
        new_project.save()
        return view_projects(request)
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot assign "<UserProfile: UserProfile object>": "Projects.client" must be a "User" instance.
```

I didn't change the models.

```
# Create a table for users
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Client Info
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    client_type = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

# Create a table to manage project requests
class Projects(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    description = models.TextField()
    budget = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    time_frame = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 3, decimal_places = 1)
    time_frame_units = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    contact_email = models.EmailField()
    contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    price_quote = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 10, decimal_places = 2)
    eta = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    current_status = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
```

Any suggestions?

UPDATE 1:
From the actual database I can see that one of the `rsb_projects` constraints is:
`rsb_projects_client_id_fkey  (client_id) REFERENCE rsb_userprofile (id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`

If that helps...

It seems to me that even though I've defined the `ForeignKey` in the `models.py` to be against `User` the database wants the `UserProfile` id.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is exactly what it says it is.

In order to create the new project you need to give your project object a **user profile object**, not a **user profile id**.

```
   user = User.objects.get(id=7)
   userprofile = user.get_profile()
   project.client = userprofile
```

Notice that it is `userprofile` object that is assigned to the project instance's client attribute.  You **cannot** assign the `userprofile` object's id to the project instance's client attribute.

Also, do not confuse your user id with your userprofile id. They may not be exactly the same.

The user id is the primary key auto-generated in the auth_user table whenever a new user is created in your database.
The userprofile id is the primary key auto-generated in the profiles_userprofile table whenever a corresponding user profile is created that is related to a user.

In other words, your `add_project` view function needs to read something like

```
if (request.method == "POST"):
    user = User.objects.get(username = request.POST.get('rsb_username'))
    # userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user = user)  <-- we don't need this anymore.

    new_project = Projects(client = user,  # <--- give it a user instance of course now that your model has changed
                           project_name = request.POST.get('rsb_project_name'),
                           description = request.POST.get('rsb_description'),
                           budget = request.POST.get('rsb_budget'),
                           time_frame = request.POST.get('rsb_time_frame'),
                           time_frame_units = request.POST.get('rsb_time_frame_units'),
                           contact = request.POST.get('rsb_point_of_contact'),
                           contact_email = request.POST.get('rsb_contact_email'),
                           contact_phone = request.POST.get('rsb_contact_phone'),
                           )
    new_project.save()
```

The key takeaway is that you need to be sure what your original model definition is.

If in your Project class, your client attribute is assigned as FK to User, then you need to give it a user object.

If in your Project class, your client attribute is assigned as FK to UserProfile, then you need to give it a userprofile object.

Comment: In your settings.py file, specify

`AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'profiles.UserProfile'`

Take note that "profiles" will be whatever you have named your userprofile app to be. If your user profile app is called userprofile, then it should be 

`AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'userprofile.UserProfile'`

THe purpose of specifying this setting is described in django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#auth-profile-module

Comment: Please disregard my previous (now deleted) comment.  It was posted before you finished answering your question.

Comment: It absolutely does.  Again, I don't fully understand it yet, but I'm going to put some time into it!  Thank you.

Comment: Play with "./manage shell" in your django project and understand the difference between an "object" and an "id" (integer).  They are two different things.  When specify a ForeignKey field, we are essentially saying that we are linking to an object, not to the id of the object.

Comment: It appears something else might be wrong here?  I'm not sure why it just suddenly stopped working.  =-/

Comment: You will need to give more details on the error. "suddenly stopped working" doesn't help... :-)

Comment: I modified my original question to update what error I'm receiving now `Cannot assign "<UserProfile: UserProfile object>": "Projects.client" must be a "User" instance.`  I don't understand why this is an error.  `Projects.client` *is* a `User instance` isn't it?  `client = models.ForeignKey(User)`

Comment: well if your `client = models.ForeignKey(User)`  is now pointing to User, obviously you will need to delete the userprofile code I placed earlier.  Essentially, whatever model your FK is pointing to, it needs to be giving the model's instance. In this updated case, a user instance.  Updating my answer accordingly...

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it is still not working.  Now I'm getting this error: `IntegrityError: insert or update on table "rsb_projects" violates foreign key constraint "rsb_projects_client_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (client_id)=(14) is not present in table "rsb_userprofile".`  I believe `Key (client_id)` is expecting the `UserProfile` id.  Suggestions?

Comment: Whenever you change your models, you need to drop that app's table and do syncdb again. `python manage.py reset [your_profile_app]`, otherwise the database still contains your old definitions and you will get this error.

When you reset your db tables, you will automatically loose your data in in. South helps you to mitigate this problem i.e. you can change your database (models) schema and yet retain data in your db.

If you intend to make a lot of changes over time to your database schema (your models.py files), I recommend that you use the `south` library to manage your schema changes.

Comment: Luckily I'm still in dev mode so that shouldn't be a problem.  Which tables should I drop?  `auth_user`, `rsb_userprofile` and 'rsb_projects`.  Those are all the tables that are `keyed` to each other.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18172/discussion-between-calvin-cheng-and-rico)